# IOS Google Sign in "No sign-in handlers installed" error

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

I am using the Google Sign-In SDK 2.1.0 for IOS.

in my login ViewController I just simply add the google signin button to my view

```
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    self.googleLoginBtn = GIDSignInButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 60))
    self.view.addSubview(self.googleLoginBtn)
```

and I got 2 testing device, in one of the device which has the Youtube App installed, when the login btn is clicked, in open the Youtube app and log me in and go back to my app. Which works perfect.

in another device with some old apps installed, it shows this error

```
<GIDSignIn: 0x167b97b0> error: Error Domain=com.google.GIDSignIn Code=-3 "No sign-in handlers installed" UserInfo=0x17fe0bf0 {NSLocalizedDescription=No sign-in handlers installed}
```

so...what should be the common practice for handling this??

override it and show a webview for the user to login?

or prompt them for no Google Sign-in handler app??

thanks.

//Update
I found that in the simulator in works, even no other app is installed, it will present a viewController for login.

but seems they didnt call in my app for both iphone (I did set a break point to verify this)

```
// Present a view that prompts the user to sign in with Google
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!,
    presentViewController viewController: UIViewController!) {
  self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// Dismiss the "Sign in with Google" view
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!,
    dismissViewController viewController: UIViewController!) {
  self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look the demo from this SDK.

```
- (void)toggleAllowSignInWithBrowser:(UISwitch *)sender {
  [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].allowsSignInWithBrowser = sender.on;
}

- (void)toggleAllowSignInWithWebView:(UISwitch *)sender {
  [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].allowsSignInWithWebView = sender.on;
}
```

So you gotta set the BOOL state to on or off(ie YES or NO)

`[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].allowsSignInWithWebView = YES;`

Comment: I have set allowsSignInWithWebView to true, it is still the same. btw, even i didn't set allowsSignInWithWebView to true, a webview still show in Simulator, but this is not work in my testing iPhone

Answer (score 0):

Hey I had a similar error and found a way around this issue. See my answer to this other issue:
[Not fetch Google user when handle sign in with another Google app using GIDSignIn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30864202/not-fetch-google-user-when-handle-sign-in-with-another-google-app-using-gidsigni/32366758#32366758)

What I found is that when I had to use my own clientserverid, it would give me either the error you have or a -1 error code. Do you need to use a clientserverid?