# Authentication through google+ fails when serverCleintID is set

Tags: objective-c, swift, google-authentication

When using the new SDK, authentication through google+ app fails if [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] setServerClientID] is set. But works when it is not set. Has anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue and found a workaround: [Not fetch Google user when handle sign in with another Google app using GIDSignIn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30864202/not-fetch-google-user-when-handle-sign-in-with-another-google-app-using-gidsigni/32366758#32366758)

I'm still looking for an acceptable solution though.